# ¿CÓMO PINTAR DENTRO DE LA CONSOLA CON COLORAMA DESDE UN DATASET?

Tags: python, funciones, windows, dataset

***Hola tengo el promedio de digits de datsets, pero quiero que se vean los numeros en la consola coloreando solo los 0 de color negro y los
números 16 de BLANCO y usar colores intermedios para los
valores entre 1 y 15 .*** AYUDA POR FAVOR porque quisiera que se vea más visible para el ojo humano los promedios y no usar excel y formato condicional para verlos sería muy tedioso.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
#librerías gratuitas para Python. Cuenta con algoritmos de clasificación, regresión, clustering y reducción de dimensionalidad.
#Pregunta: generar una matriz 8*8 con la imagen promedio
#de cada uno de los 10 dígitos
digits = datasets.load_digits()
#función ayuda a cargar y devolver el conjunto de datos de dígitos
print(digits.target)
numero = []
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
promedio = []
promedios = []
representacion = []

for i in range(len(digits.target)):
  numero.append(digits.target[i])
  representacion.append(digits.images[i])
for a in range(10):
  for i in range(len(numero)):
    if numero[i] == a:
      for j in range(8):
        lista1.append(representacion[i][j])
      lista2.append(lista1)
      lista1 = []
  for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
      x = 0
      for k in range(len(lista2)):
        x += lista2[k][i][j]
      x = x / (len(lista2))
      lista1.append(int(x))
    promedio.append(lista1)
    lista1 = []
  lista2 = []
  promedios.append(promedio)
  promedio = []
  for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
      if promedios[a][i][j] < 10:
        print(promedios[a][i][j], end="  ")
      elif promedios[a][i][j] == 0:
        #pintar de color negro solo los 0
        print(Fore.BLACK+promedios[0])
      else:
        print(promedios[a][i][j], end=" ")
    print()
  print("--------------------------------")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahora si nos cuentas cual es el problema que te impide tener lo que quieres, estaríamos más cerca de la solución.

Comment: hola, el problema es que no sé como utilizar colorama para que al imprimir el dataset me salgan los 0 pintados en la consola

Comment: Al momento de imprimir usas los colores de colorama y con eso ya podrás ver el texto de color

Comment: Ese problema se soluciona leyendo la documentación: https://pypi.org/project/colorama/.

Comment: es que ya utilizo los colores de colorama pero no me funciona sigue blanco los numeros